# Defining a continuous complex logarithm on open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, logarithms

Suppose you are given an open set $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ and a continuous function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

And $f$ has the next property:

> For every closed loop $ c: I \rightarrow U$ we have $n(f\circ c,0) = 0$ (the number of times the closed loop $f\circ c$ goes around the origin is zero).

How is this condition sufficient (it is in fact a **necessary** condition too, but that is easy to show) for the existence of a continuous function $g: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z) = e^{g(z)}$ $\forall z \in U$.

edit: $U$ is an arbitrary open set in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: This could be a useful fact:

Given a loop $c: I \rightarrow \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$,

$n(c,0)$ can be defined as the complex integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c}{\frac{dz}{z}}$

Comment: I will assume $U$ is path-connected. Pick a basepoint $z_0 \in U$, choose  a logarithm of $f(z_0)$. Then for a $z \in U$, pick a continuous path from $z_0$ to $z$, this will give you a particular "lift", or logarithm of $f$, restricted to this path. In particular, this will give a definite choice of logarithm of $f(z)$. Check that this is independent of a choice of path.

Comment: Yes indeed this is the same proof I gave if I assumed that $U$ was path-connected. But the hypothesis is just that $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ is open.

What I thought would help in that case would be, applying the same argument to all path-connected components of $U$.

But in the end I would have to use the Axiom of Choice to complete the creation of my desired function.

I thought maybe someone else would have a different proof in mind. But maybe this result is not independent of the, so controversial, Axiom of Choice in the end.

Comment: @rie: So your actual question is how to generalize the (well-known) result for connected open sets to arbitrary open sets?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know if there is an easier way than what I have in mind. That would be picking a base point and a lift on each path-connected component of $U$, and complete the definition of $g$

Comment: @rie: You might want to add that information to your question, it was not immediately obvious to me, only after reading the above comments.

Comment: @MartinR will do. Thank you.

Comment: So your problem is that you want to avoid choice? You can do that. $U$ has only countably many connected components. Take an enumeration $\{z_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of $\mathbb{Q}[i]$. For each component $C$ of $U$, let $A(C) = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : z_n \in C\}$ and $n_C = \min A(C)$. Pick $z_{n_C}$ as the base point in $C$, and choose the logarithm so that $\operatorname{Im} g(z_{n_C}) \in [0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you very much. This solves the issue